# Django: How to create an instance of a model without a form but by a button click

Tags: django, model

I am new to Django, so pardon me if my question is naive.
I am trying to achieve a use case of text mining application on uploaded files, I am trying to show a "Get Started" button in the landing / home page. On button click I am rendering a file upload option.
Now I am trying to treat this as a Scan Job, and wanting jobID to get created with the click of the button and the same jobID to be displayed further pages and this jobID to be used as primary key in other models.

Below is the model I created.

from django.db import models

```
class sfs_job_model(models.Model):
    sfs_job_id = models.CharField(max_length=250,default="", editable=True)
    sfs_job_start_date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)
    sfs_job_end_date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=False)
    sfs_job_status = models.CharField(max_length=250, editable=False,empty_value=None,null=True)
    sfs_job_summary = models.CharField(max_length=1000) 

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.job_id is None:
            self.job_id = 'SFS-' + str(self.id)
        return super(sfs_job_model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Please guide me how to achieve the desired use case.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you sfs_job_id  create as UUID and use sfs_job_id  usage anywhere are the same and unique.

```
`def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.sfs_job_id is None:
            self.sfs_job_id = 'SFS-' + self.sfs_job_start_date_time.isoformat()
        return super(sfs_job_model, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`
```

Comment: Thank you Gaurav for a quick response. Can you please guide me how to create instance of the model with a button click.in HTML

Comment: I mean to ask without using forms

Comment: use instance get_or_create() method. if instance obj not exits then create the obj then update obj value and save the obj using obj.save() more information read this document(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/)